# Solaris Dependency Walker?

Tags: java, c++, solaris, jna

Is there a Dependency Walker sort of tool in Solaris.

My objective is to verify these:-

1. From Java native(c++) function invocation happens?
2. From Java all parameter passed is received at native(c++) without corruption?
3. To log invocations from java to c++.

Thanks and Regards
Srinivasan

Answer (score 1):

Solaris has a dependency walker. It's called `ldd`.

Your run it like this:

```
ldd your-executable
```

It will list all shared libraries that your executable uses.

But according to your description, you're looking for something that I wouldn't call *dependency walker*. And I doubt it exists.